# How to insert pictures with LaTex + dvips + ps2pdf quick build?

Tags: graphics, errors, diagrams, preamble, compilation-error

I am using a quick build of "LaTex + dvips + ps2pdf + view PDF".

> What is the easiest way to insert (multiple) pictures?

I am fairly comfortable with LaTeX but I have never done this before. So if someone could give me a step-by-step guide (including any package I need to add to the preamble or where to put the folder of my images), it would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT: *I am now getting the error File "intro" not found, which makes me think I may have saved my images in the wrong folder?***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pst-poker} 
\usepackage{graphicx} %graphics for the cards%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Property}


\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{intro}.

\includegraphics[height=3cm]{intro}\includegraphics[width=5cm]{intro}

\includegraphics[height=3cm]{intro} \includegraphics[width=5cm]{intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics

Comment: Thank you, I am making progress (see updated text) although I have a feeling that perhaps I am saving the pictures in the wrong place?

Comment: @Pellenthor What file type is `intro`? An .eps image or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Key: For dvi compiling one would need .eps images (thank you @samcarter)**

The steps are as follows:

> 1. Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble
> 2. Save your image in the SAME folder as your .tex file
> 3. Convert the image to .eps using an online converter like [this one](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-eps)
> 4. Use `\includegraphics{picture_name}` in the main OR
> 5. Use `\includegraphics{folder_name/picture_name}` (if you saved the picture in a folder)
> 6. For more adjustments (size, colors etc) consider [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Importing_external_graphics)